# CHAR(0) allows to insert values of all lengths in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working with mysql. I am confused over datatype char(0). Even though as per definition the columnlength is 0, it is still allowing to add string of greater length then what does the length zero signify?

Edit: Also the value is not even retained. on query it returns empty string.

Comment: Even though you can specify any length as you said, it won't save anything except `null` and `''` (empty string). Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: It must give an error at insertion like "Data Too Long" or like somthing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid a number of confusing behaviours like this you need to configure MySQL in strict mode. I normally execute this in my SQL client so I get coherent behaviour no matter server settings:

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

Just see the difference:

```
mysql> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('x');
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'bar' at row 1
mysql> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode=''; -- Older default
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('x');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'bar' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Mjh I was basically referring to the fact that MySQL was initially designed after the idea that corrupting user data silently was a feature but it wasn't my intention to start a flame so I'll gladly edit the answer and change the term.

Comment: Comment removed, I don't want to flame either, I just wanted to know what you were referring to. +1, good answer, world is at peace :)